# Inserting data using ajax issue

Tags: php, ajax

I am trying to insert data on my database using ajax, nothing is working.  Can any tell me what I am doing wrong please?

INDEX.PHP

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Title</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function myLoad(){
                if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
                    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                }else{
                    var xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
                }

                xmlhttp.open('GET', 'generate.php?text=' + document.getElementById('textarea').value, true);
                xmlhttp.send();
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
                    if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
                        window.document.getElementById('par').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                    }
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="par"></div>
        <input type="text" id="textarea">
        <input type="button" id="button" value="Click Me" onClick="myLoad();"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

GENERATE.PHP

```
<?php
    require 'php/connect.inc.php';

    if(isset($_GET['text']) && !empty($_GET['text'])){
        $name = $_GET['text'];
        $query = "INSERT INTO users VALUES('', '$name', 'pass123', 'greg')";

        if($mysql_query = mysql_query($query)){
            echo 'Success';
        }else{
            echo 'Failed';
        }
    }
?>
```

CONNECT.INC.PHP

```
<?php
    $mysql_host = 'localhost';
    $mysql_user = 'root';
    $mysql_pass = '';

    $mysql_error = 'Could not connect';
    $a_database = 'a_database';

    if(!@mysql_connect($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_pass) OR !@mysql_select_db($a_database)){
        die($mysql_error);
    }
?>
```

Comment: You get a blank screen when you click the button?

Comment: you need to add some more information.. "nothing is working" is a bit vague.. Are you debugging using IE/chrome with F12 to check network traffic?  Can you see that the request is actually sent? Is there a response?

Comment: Oh sorry about that? No I meant, I never get any result, but the button and the text field is still there

Comment: I think you will have to send the response back instead of just using "echo"

Comment: Check the `xmlhttp.status` before your if block in the onreadystatechange handler, and see what it is.

Comment: @ganesh echo sends the response back. Any output will be sent back.

Comment: Have you tried pulling up generate.php by itself to verify that it is working?

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the cause of your entire problem, but could be confusing the issue.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO users VALUES('', '$name', 'pass123', 'greg')";
```

If you are using Mysql5+ and the first of those VALUES is an autoincremented id number, then that INSERT will fail.  Either leave it out, make it a null or a 0 (unquoted) the empty string '' insert was a "feature" of Mysql4 which should not have worked.

ie from Mysql5 onwards ....

```
$query = "INSERT INTO users VALUES(0, '$name', 'pass123', 'greg')";
```